# Understand and use the basic concept of Haskell's Integral typeclass

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I'm taking a course which focuses on Haskell & Prolog and there's an upcoming test for which i'm studying.

We're given a signature:

```
myList
  :: (Integral a)
  => [a]
```

And we have to create a variable `myList` which will return an infinite list which is different from standard positive integer list by changing the position of every third element by moving it two positions to the right, starting from the first one.

So for example, the beginning would look like:
`2,3,1,5,6,4,8,9,7..` on a standard list which contains positive elements.

I tried to solve this with a code like this:

```
myList (x:y:z:xs)
  = y:z:x:(myList(xs))
myList [] = []
myList [x] = [x]
```

It gives the result needed but it's not following the signature. Could someone explain how to solve it so it would fit the signature and why it does.

Thanks.

Comment: "gives the result needed" — how do you obtain it?

Comment: Hint: Integral is not a type, and you don't have to understand it in order to solve this assignment. Just ignore it for now.

Comment: Well i do have to get it according to the signature and i can't figure out how can i get it. My current :t gives out [a] -> [a]

Comment: @n.m. I called it out to test: myList (take 100 [1,2..])

Comment: The code you wrote is a *function* that alters an existing list. The requirement appears to be to produce a list, not modify an existing one.

Comment: Good. Do you know what will happen if you call just `myList [1,2..]`?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I understand what you meant however i don't understand the importance of this thing. Also i do not have any clue how to do it in this manner.

Comment: @n.m. Well then it will work for infinite time in the same way. The take 100 is just to see whether it works or not. The question is how should i rewrite it so it would be according to the signature (If we don't have it by the correct signature we will be graded with 0 points even if we get the right solution).

Comment: Great, you are almost there. You could have tested it this way instead: `take 100 (myList [1,2..])`. Incidentally, this means that `myList` could be made simpler, as it only ever needs to see infinite lists. Thus, no need to provide `[]` and `[x]` cases. OK?

Comment: Your function still has a wrong signature. Let's rename it to `wrongList`. Now you have this expression `wrongList [1,2..]` that is exactly the list you need, which is `myList`. What you have to do now is write an *equation* that states just this fact.

Comment: `myList = [2,5..] >>= \k -> [k,k+1,k-1]`

Comment: Just between these two, wrongList and myList @n.m.? Okay i tested and it gave me an :: Integer as a signature when i did myList = wrongList [1,2..]. I may have misunderstood you..

Comment: `myList = wrongList [1,2..]` should be exactly what you need. What exact output you are getting from ghci?

Comment: @user2407038 Great, now explain `>>=` like I'm five.

Comment: @Banana: off topic, but since you mentioned Haskell & Prolog together, do you know about FLP (Functional Logic Programming)? A prominet example of an FLP language, which I happen to be studying currently, would be [Curry](http://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/kics2/) (tag: [tag:curry]).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function (the implementation of which you got perfectly right, as a matter of fact)

```
myList (x:y:z:xs) = y:z:x:(myList xs)
myList []         = []
myList [x]        = [x]
```

is generic enough not to depend on the type of the elements in the list to be `Integral a => a`. So if you let Haskell infer its type, it will infer `[a] -> [a]`. If you constraint the type to `Integral a => [a] -> [a]`, it will still work, but be less generic, which will limit uses to just integral types.

---

Here's a demonstration of the principle:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let myList (x:y:z:xs) = y:z:x:(myList(xs))
Prelude|     myList [] = []
Prelude|     myList [x] = [x]
Prelude| :}
Prelude> :t myList
myList :: [a] -> [a]

Prelude> take 15 $ myList ['a'..]
"bcaefdhigkljnom"
Prelude> take 15 $ myList [1..]
[2,3,1,5,6,4,8,9,7,11,12,10,14,15,13]
```

but

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let myList :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
Prelude|     myList (x:y:z:xs) = y:z:x:(myList(xs))
Prelude|     myList [] = []
Prelude|     myList [x] = [x]
Prelude| :}
Prelude> :t myList
myList :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]

Prelude> take 15 $ myList [1..]
[2,3,1,5,6,4,8,9,7,11,12,10,14,15,13]

Prelude> take 15 $ myList ['a'..]    
<interactive>:34:11:
    No instance for (Integral Char) arising from a use of ‘myList’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘myList ['a' .. ]’
    In the expression: take 15 $ myList ['a' .. ]
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = take 15 $ myList ['a' .. ]
```

---

**So the point is**, both definitions are equivalent and capable of doing the same thing just as well as the other, but the constrained type signature is (and I'd say unjustifiably) less useful than the one with the general type signature.

If the assignment demands a function of type `Integral a => [a] -> [a]`, all you really need to do is simply annotate the function you already have with exactly that type signature. There is, however, no (reasonable/rational) way  to somehow guide Haskell to infer that type from the function definition, as that would necessitate somehow indirectly indicating that the list must contain values of a type that support the operations in `Integral` ... yada yada.

**As a final note**: you got the implementation/algorithm perfectly right, but fell short on type signatures and the notion of generality.

---

**EDIT:** if what you actually need is not a function but a list (your question is a bit ambiguous in this respect), all you need to do is rename the below definition of `myList` to e.g. `myList'` or `go` (which I think is quite a typical name for nested recursive helpers) or something (which can but doesn't have to be an hidden within the list `myList`) and then pass `[1..]` to it, assigning the result to `myList`:

```
myList :: Integral a => [a]
myList = go [1..]
  where go (x:y:z:xs) = y:z:x:(go xs)
        go []         = []
        go [x]        = [x]
```

of course looked this way, `Integral a => [a]` *is* indeed quite general a signature for the list (but not the most general, which would be `(Enum a, Num a) => [a]` as I was led to realize by dfeuer's comment), because the type `a` cannot be determined by the type of the input passed to the function, because you're always passing `[1..]`.

Comment: "If the assignment demands a function of type Integral a => [a] -> [a]," The assignment asks for `Integral a => [a]` though - not a function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and answer :)

Comment: Just a stupid follow up question. If i set the type: myList :: Integral a => [a] -> [a] in a .hs file, I get an error. Is this in there for illustration or have i done something wrong.

Comment: Ambigious occurrence 'null': It could either refer to 'Data.List.null' or 'Data.Set.null'

Comment: Don't import Data.Set

Comment: @Banana: we'd have to see the error in full, together with the source code (in case you haven't nailed it by now). @sepp2k: right you are — I took a look at the implementation of `myList` and saw it was a function; that, combined with the rest of the information in the post (except the signature at the very beginning), lead me to assume the OP did indeed mean a function. However, nonetheless, it's trivial to adapt the answer to get the right solution.

Comment: I don't see how your solution can typecheck. `[1..] :: (Num a, Enum a) => [a]`. You probably want to fix `a ~ Int` and map `fromIntegral` over the result. Then you can manually restrict it to `Integral n` from `Num n` if you like.

Comment: `:i Integral` shows `(Real a, Enum a) => Integral a` and of course `(Num a, Ord a) => Real a`... so what do you mean? The snippet typechecks and runs exactly as advertised.

Comment: I had no idea `Enum a => Integral a`. Oops!

Comment: Well it's kind of obvious if you recall that the `succ` and `pred` operations are quite fundamental to integer values, at least considering the Peano representation...

Comment: The `Enum` class is so badly broken I tend to do my best to pretend it doesn't even exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94265/discussion-between-erik-allik-and-dfeuer).

Answer (score 0):

If we want to give an answer with the right signature *without* supplying any signatures by hand, we have to look at the Integral class and look which methods it implements. Applying any such method is likely to force the right signature.

```
Prelude> :i Integral
class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where
  quot :: a -> a -> a
  rem :: a -> a -> a
  div :: a -> a -> a
  mod :: a -> a -> a
  quotRem :: a -> a -> (a, a)
  divMod :: a -> a -> (a, a)
  toInteger :: a -> Integer
```

Since our sequence has something to do with remainders of division by 3, `div` and `mod` look promising.

After some fiddling with arithmetic, we arrive at something like

```
Prelude> let myList = map (\x -> x - x `mod` 3 + (x+2) `mod` 3 + 1) [0..]
Prelude> :t myList
myList :: Integral b => [b]
```